# CSS, JS: Avoid flash of page before ScrollTo()

Tags: javascript, css

I am changing page content by setting display:none/block on the DIVs that I want to hide/show. For some content I want the page to start scrolled down by some amount. I use scrollTo() for that.

This works fine on my desktop, but on my iPad, I see a flash of the new content before it scrolls down, or, I see a flash of the old content as scrolled down before it disappears. Everything doesn't happen instantly enough.

What is the solution to this? I've tried reordering the order in which I hide and show the content.

```
<body>

  <div>header and navigation stuff</div>

  <div id = "content_1">
      content 2
      <button id = "button_goto_2">goto_2</div>
  </div>

  <div id = "content_2" style = "display:none">
      content 2
      ..
      ..
  </div>

</body>
```

Jquery:

```
$("html").on("click", "#button_goto_2", function(event) { 

    $("#content_1").css("display","none"); 
    $("#content_2").css("display","block");
    window.scrollTo(0,100); // It is not always 100

})
```

Comment: instead of showing then hiding the content, hide it then show it

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried reordering. It just changes whether I see a flash of the old or the new content with wrong scroll (or makes no difference sometimes).

Comment: so you have a class on those divs and display:none in the css, then after page-load you're removing the class on the divs you want to show?

Comment: When you use display:none, the element effectively disappears, and the other element will move up to the same position as the old element. Maybe try just changeing opacity to 0 or use visibility:hidden.

Comment: @Splashdust: I do need the element to effectively disappear. Dave Briand, Yes, I guess so. If you mean what I think you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the complete function of jQuery events should do the trick:

```
$('#content_1').hide(10, function() {

  $('#content_2').css({'visibility': 'hidden'}).show(10, function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,100);
    $('#content_2').css({'visibility': 'visible'});
  });
});
```

Comment: Won't that just show content 2 briefly unscrolled before scrolling down? I tried something similar with jquery's done(), controllign the order, but it didn't solve anything. I essentially need 3 things to happen instantaneously, but, I guess the iPad is too slow (or something) to handle it this way.

Comment: The time in both hide and show is the time in milliseconds it take to go from visible (as in `display: block`) to invisible (as in `display: none`) by variying  the `opacity` level (reverse for show). Once it's invisible, the complete function is executed. So this code will very quickly hide content_1 then very quickly show content_2 then scroll. The effect is that the 2 animations are queue instead of overlapping.

Comment: Edited to hide the visibility until the scrolling has started.

Comment: Ok, so it actually magically seemed to work, also without hiding the visibility! Thanks!